# Mostrar etiqueta <a> al pasar puntero

Tags: javascript, html5, css

buenas tengo el siguiente problema, estoy realizando una pagina, y tengo dos etiquetas  y quiero que al pasar el puntero por encima de una me aparezca, recién me aparezca la otra etiqueta, la cual tiene un icono, alguna idea?

```html
<a href="edit.php">Editar</a><a href="" class="color"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
```

Comment: puedes detallar mejor tu pregunta porfavor

Comment: perdon si no se a entendio.. de las dos etiquetas que tengo lo que qiero es que la segunda este oculta.. y en el momento que pase el mause por la primer etiqueta, en ese momento recien aparesca la segunda etiqueta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function(){

    $('#dos').hide();
    $('div').hover(function(){
        $('div').toggle();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="uno">
   <a href="edit.php">Editar</a>
</div>  

<div id="dos">   
   <a href="" class="color"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
</div>
```

> no desapersca la primera... que se mantega, y la segunda aparesca al
>   lado

```css
.contenedor{
width:15%;
}

a:first-of-type + a{
visibility: hidden;
}

.contenedor:hover>a:nth-of-type(2){
visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor"> 

   <a href="edit.php" class="uno">Editar</a>

   <a href="" class="color"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por responder..en realidad es lo que qiero pero, con la diferencia que no desapersca la primera... que se mantega, y la segunda aparesca al lado

Comment: muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo, era lo que necesitava, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Se puede realizar con `CSS` puro usando un contenedor para los links y en el momento que se hacer `hover` aparece el segundo link:

```css
div { 
  width: 100px; /* contenedor */
}

.esconder {
  visibility: hidden; /* esconde el segundo <a> */
}

div:hover > .esconder {  
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>  
  <a href="#1">Editar</a> 
  <a class="esconder" href="#2" class="color"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>    
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Una solución *diferente* y más simple ya que fue la primera solución posteriormente *duplicado*.

Usamos el selector `+` adyacente, el cual selecciona el próximo elemento cual se encuentra justo detrás en el código `HTML` y sin necesidad de tener un contenedor.

El segundo vinculo se muestra solo si estamos encima del primero.

```css
a {    
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

a:hover { color: red; }

.esconder { display: none; }

.mostrar:hover + .esconder,
.esconder:hover {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a class="mostrar" href="#1">Editar</a>
<a class="esconder" href="#2" class="color"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo asigné a la etiqueta los eventos sin considerar las que contiene la clase "color", asimismo, en dicha clase por defecto lo puse oculto.

```js
$("a").not('.color').mouseover(function() {
   $(this).next().toggle();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).next().hide();
  });
```

```css
.color{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="edit.php">Editar</a><a href="" class="color"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
```